# Ubuntu 14.04 Server GUI Installation and RDp Acess through windows 10

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, rdp

How to install GUI for Ubuntu 14.04 and get RDP Access over windows ??

I have a laptop running on windows 10. I want to acess the linux machine running in Hyper V Enviornment with GUI .

This Linux machine is going to be used for web development ,specifically angular JS ./
What are the best practices that can be used to do this . I want a virtual Setup that has to run in a Hyper V Environment and can be accessed from Client Machine using Putty or RDP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[xrdp](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/xrdp) is tool that you can install on Ubuntu 14.04 and access ubuntu remotely with RDP from any windows machine. First you need to install any desktop environment. I suggest you to go with [LXDE](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5357) the lightest one.